# Is the rotation matrix unique for a given rotation?

Tags: rotation, computer-vision, rotational-matrices

I found two rotation matrices

```
rot1 = [    0.8736    0.2915   -0.3897;
           -0.4011    0.8848   -0.2373;
            0.2756    0.3636    0.8898]

rot2 = [    0.9874   -0.1420   -0.0700;
            0.0700    0.7880   -0.6117;
            0.1420    0.5991    0.7880]
```

when multiplying the vector

```
wpt = [200 200 200]
```

producing the same result

```
cpt = [155.0812 49.2660 305.8148]
```

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're actually asking two questions here.

### Are rotation matrices unique?

Yes they are, as [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105380) that Francesco quoted explains well. If they were not unique, then **Q*v = R*v** and thus  **(Q-R)*v = 0** would be true for any vector. The latter is only true for the null matrix, however.

It may help you to look at the angle-axis representation of your two rotations to see that they are not identical (the format is x,y,z and angle):

```
>> vrrotmat2vec(rot1)

    0.5304   -0.5873   -0.6114    0.6022

>> vrrotmat2vec(rot2)

    0.9707   -0.1700    0.1700    0.6734
```

Alternatively, you can look at each of the rows of your rotation matrix, which represent the unit vectors of your rotated spaces, and see that they are different from each other. ([source](https://www.fastgraph.com/makegames/3drotation/), properties 3 and 4)

### Why are these two rotation matrices giving the same result for this vector?

Because a point can be mapped to another point by infinitely many rotations. For any two rotations around the same center, some points* end up moving to the same place. If you will, rot1 and rot2 move your point wpt to cpt along different rotation arcs in 3D space.

[image: The rotation arcs and axes of your point and matrices]

Since this plot really isn't helpful in 2D and you seem to have access to MATLAB, you can just generate the figure yourself and pan around it with this code:

```
vr1 = vrrotmat2vec(rot1);
vr2 = vrrotmat2vec(rot2);
v = [1;1;1];
arc1 = [];
arc2 = [];
for i = 1:50
    a = vrrotvec2mat([vr1(1:3) i*vr1(4)/50]);
    arc1 = [arc1; (a*v)'];
    a = vrrotvec2mat([vr2(1:3) i*vr2(4)/50]);
    arc2 = [arc2; (a*v)'];
end

%% Drawing
% Arcs
plot3(arc1(:,1), arc1(:,2), arc1(:,3))
hold on
plot3(arc2(:,1), arc2(:,2), arc2(:,3))

% Unit vectors
arrow([0 0 0], [1 0 0]);
arrow([0 0 0], [0 1 0]);
arrow([0 0 0], [0 0 1]);

% Rotation axes
arrow([0 0 0], vr1(1:3), 'EdgeColor','b','FaceColor','g');
arrow([0 0 0], vr2(1:3), 'EdgeColor','r','FaceColor','g');

axis square
```

* I am guessing the points lie on exactly two lines, but I can't back that up.

Answer (score 0):

Non uniqueness means that the equality rot1 * v = rot2 * v applies to every vector v.  See [this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105380)